# bq command is not able to authorize

Tags: google-bigquery, gcloud, gsutil

From my server, I have set the project and also set the active service account. I am able to fire the *gsutil* command successfully, but getting an error when running the bq command.

The error is

> Authorization error. This may be a network connection problem,so please try again. If this problem persists, the credentials may be corrupt.

The Error trace is

> HttpAccessTokenRefreshError: Invalid JWT Signature

Comment: I would suggest to delete your service account and create it again or restart the environment you are using. Typically this helps to solve such issues.

Comment: Could you confirm if your issue was resolved? If not, some additional information will be useful: are you rotating the key? what version of Google Cloud SDK are you using (it is recommended to use the last one available)?

Answer (score 1):

Some possible causes of the error:

- The propagation of the activated key can be delayed. Below caveat was mentioned on GCP's reference about [service account key](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#creating_service_account_keys):

  > It may take up to *60 seconds* before a newly created key can be used for authentication. If you experience authentication failures immediately after creating a new key, ensure that 60 seconds have elapsed before trying again.
- `bq` command's SDK somehow caches the account key and handles it differently from `gsutil`'s SDK. This can be the reason why the authentication works when running `gsutil`.

There can be times that the propagation may take longer than 60 seconds before it can be used.